# Combinatorics select 3 cards out of 52, probability all 3 spades and not.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

You get $3$ cards out of $52$, the order doesn't matter.

a) What is the probability all $3$ cards are spades?

b) What is the probability none of the $3$ cards are spades?

a) I think it is $$\frac{\binom{13}{3}}{\binom{52}{3}}\approx 0.012941$$
b) I know it is $$=\frac{\binom{39}{3}}{\binom{52}{3}}\approx 0.41353$$

My problem is that I know $P(A^c)= 1 - P(A)$

And if a is $A$ and b is $A^c$ the equation above is not correct..

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that the complement of the event "all of the $3$ cards are spades" is "at least one of the $3$ cards is not a spade" not "none of the $3$ cards are spades".

So, $P(``\text{all of the 3 cards are spades}")+P(``\text{none of the 3 cards are spades}") < 1$.

Comment: Thank you! PS I cannot format my math correctly... sorry Also I cannot upvote you...

Comment: Do you know of any rules that apply to the complements of events? A link or a book maybe? The book I have doesn't provide any elaborate examples about complements. Thank you again!

Comment: Ok I found something. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Let $P(n)$ be the probability that $n$ cards are drawn.  $P(3)$ is the answer for a), and you got that right.  The answer for b) is $P(0)$.

$P(0) + P(1) + P(2) + P(3) = 1$, so $P(0) + P(3) < 1$.

$$P(n) = \frac{\binom{13}{n}\binom{39}{3-n}}{\binom{52}{3}}$$

Comment: I think I disagree. For b) you have to find the ways you can get 3 cards out of 52-13=39 (all minus a suit) / all the ways you can select 3 out of 52.

Comment: Ah.  I misread the question.

Comment: It's ok! Thank you for answering!